# IDEA сгенерировала equals помогите разобраться

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IDEA сгенерировала код, мог бы кто-то построчно его прокомментировать. Не понимаю, как он работает.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Pair<?, ?> pair = (Pair<?, ?>) o;

    if (first != null ? !first.equals(pair.first) : pair.first != null) return false;
    return !(second != null ? !second.equals(pair.second) : pair.second != null);

}
```

Comment: first где-то объявлен?

Comment: да, конечно, вопрос уже решён, спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    //Если объект, с которым происходит сравнение, этим же объектом и является, то они равны. Сравнивает ссылки текущего объекта и принятого как аргумент.
    if (this == o) return true;
    //Если принятый объект null или другого класса, то возвращает false, не равны. При o == null они не равны, т.к. у null не может быть метода equals. Следовательно основной объект не null. 
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    //кастует 'o' в Pair<?, ?> pair, чтобы иметь доступ к методам.
    Pair<?, ?> pair = (Pair<?, ?>) o;

    //Проверяет что свойство first текущего объекта не равен null. Если не равен, то сравнивает first текущего объекта, с pair.first. В случае, если они не равны, то ! инвертирует в true и условие if выполняется. Выполнится return false. Объекты не равны.
    //Если first равен null, то проверяет pair.first. Если pair.first не равен null, то объекты не равны, возвращает false.
    if (first != null ? !first.equals(pair.first) : pair.first != null) return false;

    //Проверяет, что second  не равен null. 
    //Если не равен, то сравнивает second с pair.second. 
    //Если second == pair.second, то сначала первый ! в  "!second.equals(pair.second)" инвертирует его в его в false, а второй !, который идет сразу после return, инвертирует в true. Значит вернет true, объекты равны.
    //Если second == null, то проверяет второе условие. Если pair.second != null, то вернет true, который инвертируется в false.
    return !(second != null ? !second.equals(pair.second) : pair.second != null);

}
```

В общем, почитайте про тернарный оператор `?:`. Это короткий вариант if-else.

**Обновление**

В Java все, кроме примитивов (`int`, `char` и т.п.), является объектом и наследуется от класса `Object`, т. е. объект любого класса можно привести к `Object`, будь то `String`, `ArrayList`, `Integer` или `MyClass`. На предыдущей строке идет проверка, что оба сравниваемых объекта принадлежат 1 классу `getClass() != o.getClass()`. Если программа проходит эту строку, значит они одного класса, соответственно имеют одинаковые свойства и методы. Для того, чтобы привести объект класса Object к другому классу, используется кастование(cast). `String str = (String) object;` Читайте про наследование.

Comment: //кастует 'o' в Pair<?, ?> pair, чтобы иметь доступ к методам.
    Pair<?, ?> pair = (Pair<?, ?>) o;

смогли бы это подробнее объяснить?